# Difference between the atomic structure of soft and hard ferromagnets

Tags: electromagnetism

All ferromagnets have domains in which the magnetic atomic dipoles are alligned. However, soft ferromagnets like iron respond quickly to the external magnetic fields while the hard ferromagnets(permanent ferromagnets) don't. In atomic view, what causes this difference? My fist guess is that in the hard ferromagnets the atomic dipoles are stronger and their density is higher so that their greater interaction keeps them more alligned compared to the soft ferromagnets. So,the hard ferromagnets are not affected by external magnetic field as easily as soft ferromagnets? I would appreciate if anyone please help me with that.

Comment: I think the term should be  "atomic or molecular  structure" from the table here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Ferromagnetic_materials

Answer (score 2):

the differences have to do with the microstructure of the material, as follows.

both types of ferromagnets consist almost entirely of iron with very minor additions of carbon. pure, "soft" iron contains essentially no carbon while "hard" steel contains a few tenths of a percent of carbon. That carbon makes the steel hard (resistant to deformation) by interfering with the mobility of defects in the crystalline structure of the iron; it is the ability of those defects to move that causes the pure iron to be ductile.

Now note that a chunk of iron or steel consists of millions of tiny crystals or *grains* of iron; within any single grain the iron atoms are all aligned in one crystallographic direction which makes every grain a little magnet. Those alignments are all random between grains and so an unmagnetized chunk has no net magnetization. Turning that chunk into a magnet requires us to realign all the spin axies within all the grains so they all point in pretty much the same direction.

Rotating the spin axies is resisted by the presence of carbon within the iron matrix, so much so that it takes significant amounts of work to get them swung around, and once thus aligned it takes work to randomize them again. In contrast, the absence of carbon in soft iron makes it relatively easy to align the spin axies- and also easy to randomize them again.

In this sense the thing that makes steel hard also produces a "hard" magnet, and the thing that makes pure iron soft makes it a "soft" magnet. Making a chunk of hard steel easy to magnetize can be done by heating it up to a point where the diffusive mobility of the *interstitial carbon* within the crystalline matrix is so big that it cannot interfere with realigning the spins. Then you apply an external magnetizing field, align the spins, and hold the field on while cooling the chunk back to room temperature.

This also means that you can destroy a permanent magnet by heating it up to that critical temperature which allows the grains to spontaneously randomize themselves.